# YouTube embedded player crashed with gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I made an iOS app with UIWebView which loads YouTube iFrame player.
Everything went well and it can even keep playing video on background with only one problem.

This problem only happens since this month, and it happens not only on the latest update (iOS 8.3) but also on iOS 8.1, so I figure that it has something to do with some recent modification on the YouTube iFrame API.

On iOS 8 (only iOS 8 on the device, not any iOS before 8, and not even on the emulator,) when I put the app to background (e.g. go to home screen, lock the device,) the video plays normally, but once the video is finished and the app tries to load the next video on the app's playlist, the app crashes (actually it seems like iOS forces terminating it.)

There is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the WebThread with

`libGPUSupportMercury.dylib gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient`

and the relevent call stack in the crash log is as below:

```
Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x000000018b829f90 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12
1   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x000000018b82af3c gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 168
2   WebCore                         0x0000000191620820 WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 528
3   WebCore                         0x0000000191e93ce0 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::initializeNewContext() + 1136
4   WebCore                         0x0000000191e93594 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::WebGLRenderingContext(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>, WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::Attributes) + 600
5   WebCore                         0x0000000191e92c54 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::create(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*, WebCore::WebGLContextAttributes*) + 1144
6   WebCore                         0x000000019132f6ec WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContext(WTF::String const&, WebCore::CanvasContextAttributes*) + 312
```

simply put, in my understanding, when I call YTPlayer.loadVideoById(...) YouTube API loads the video and tries to create a new WebGL rendering context, which iOS does not allow (GL rendering related instructions during background mode is not allowed,) so it terminates the app.

I've been googling and scratching my head for a whole week to deal with this but without any luck, does anyone has any idea how to deal with it?

Thank you so much for any suggestion and any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I still don't have a working solution for this problem but I just figured out a work around.

It seems like YouTube iFrame player does not create WebGL rendering context as long as you don't call YTPlayer.loadVideoById (or cueVideoById, loadVideoByUrl, cueVideoByUrl, loadPlaylist, cuePlaylist.) So I just load all the video on my playlist with loadPlaylist whenever the playlist is changed.

With this work around, my app doesn't crash anymore. It's good but I still wonder if anyone has a real solution for this, please let me know and it's very much appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm facing this problem too, but find no solution. How you "load all the video on my playlist with loadPlaylist whenever the playlist is changed" ? Could you post some code snippets here?

Comment: I am having the same problem but I *think* I have fixed it .. did you try Listing 3 at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html ?

Comment: I've read the article but I think I missed this part... I haven't tried it but I guess there is a good chance this might work. Would you post this again as an answer so I can vote it?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it (I work in Unity so any Obj-C work I do is in linked libraries and hence I am having trouble implementing it). Is there a way you can try it quickly in your environment?

Comment: @Jim I haven't had time to test your way until now, the answer is yes, removing AVPlayer does fix the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ChezHung can you elaborate on your 'loadPlaylist' method and your 'Listing 3' approach?  I couldn't get either of those solutions to work for me. Specifically, it keeps failing for iPhone5 and 5c on 8.3 or 8.4. Thx.

Comment: @JonE Yes, both ways work for me on iPhone5 and above, iOS 7.1 above.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to access playerLayer in ytplayer, but [ ytPlayerView removeWebView ]; does the work, and so is [ ytPlayerView loadWithVideoId:@"yout_video_id_here" ];

Comment: @Bastet Could you please explain how you made it work using removeWebView?

Comment: @RaduMatei I follow the Listing 3 from @ Jim,
call removeWebView in applicationDidEnterBackground. 
call loadWithVideoId: in applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: So I guess the only way to circumvent this problem and play audio in the background is 1) just remove the entire UIWebView and just stop playing, or 2) Put the videosID in a playlist with loadPlaylist to make sure that no new GL Rendering instructions occur.. I have an app that searches for a video corresponding with a certain Text String Entry. I have to initiate a YTPlayer.loadVideoById call, since I will get the ID when the previous video is at the end.. I didn't find any way so far to do this in the background.. To bad.. it used to work fine for the last 3 years ;((

Comment: Wait, there is no removing of the UIWebViews involving at all, after all, that's the whole point keeping it there. The only thing to do is to find the AVPlayerLayer in the sub view of the UIWebView, and remove the AVPlayer from it.

Comment: Can someone post the code of how they accomplished this? I'm still pretty confused. @ChezHung

Comment: @lagoon This might help. https://github.com/AnthonyMDev/youtube-ios-player-helper/commit/53370f7be8b82c0282856d96d4af9f27169071c0

Comment: @Chez Hung can you please share your code to load video in playlist?