# loadWithVideoId ios pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.6"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube

I am using youtube-ios-player-helper in my iOS App. I have created a demo project to use it and everything works fine with pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.4'. But when I implement same in my project, My App gets a crash with the error 
 **-[UIView loadWithVideoId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**.
 I am sending the correct Video Id and the video is playing in the browser, it is playing in my demo app. What is the issue in my Project?

Any helps will be appreciated,

Comment: Check this link it may helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742314/youtube-embedded-player-crashed-with-gpus-returnnotpermittedkillclient-on-ios-8

Comment: I don't know on what purpose you are using youtube-api, but if your main intension it to play youtube video, you can simply use webview only.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880101/how-to-embed-youtube-video-on-ios-and-play-it-directly-on-uiwebview-without-full

Comment: @Sivajee Battina I have to play youtube Videos  in a screen, earlier using youtube-ios-[player-helper all was working fine. But now it has started giving me an error. I am confused as what could be the problem. Also, before this my video was playing in that frame only and now today it is going on fullscreenmode. All this has happened today!!! 2 days back everything was fine!!!!

Comment: Your view is a `UIView`, not a `YTPlayerView`. Either the class is not set in Storyboard, or you just didn't set the correct in your code.